# How do I get the server time using REST GET HTTP?

Tags: 8

Is it possible to get the time from Drupal 8 with GET HTTP and REST?

I get the date format from /entity/date_format/long, which returns a value similar to the following one.

```
{
"uuid": "76e070cb-a783-47bf-89cc-db9f393a7d59",
"langcode": "en",
"status": true,
"dependencies": [],
"id": "long",
"label": "Default long date",
"locked": false,
"pattern": "l, F j, Y - H:i"
```

}

It is not what I need. I need to get the server time, so I can after synchronize some dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/entity/date_format/long` is just giving information on the date format

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is probably to create a simple [custom REST resource](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources) in a custom module and within the resource you can return the server time using php functions

```
$message = [
    'time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'timezone' => date_default_timezone_get(),
];
```

You also have to implement `CacheableResponseInterface` in order to get the current time on every call to the service otherwise you are going to get a cached response.

Here is a working [REST API time service](https://github.com/GiorgosK/time_service) module for this which I did just for the sake of this exercise

Answer (score 2):

The Rest module in Drupal 8 defines some routes that allow to view/modify some entities a Drupal site has. Since the current server time is not an entity, the module doesn't define a route to expose that value.

You can implement a route that exposes that value, in a custom module, for example defining a route like the following one.

```
mymodule.server_time.http:
  path: '/mymodule/server_time'
  defaults:
    _controller: \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\RestController::serverTime
  methods: [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
    _format: 'json'
```

`RestController::serverTime()` would then use code similar to the following one, to return the server time and the timezone.

```
public function serverTime() {
  return new JsonResponse([
    'timezone' => $this->timeSettings->get('timezone.default') ?: @date_default_timezone_get(),
    'time' => $this->time->getCurrentTime(),
  ]);
}
```

The necessary services would be injected from the following code.

```
public function __construct(Config $time_settings, TimeInterface $time) {
  $this->timeSettings = $time_settings;
  $this->time = $time;
}

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
  return new static($container->get('config.factory')->get('system.date'), $container->get('datetime.time'));
}
```

Using the *datetime.time* service is important when creating tests, which require predictable timestamps. It is preferable to using PHP functions to get the current time.

The controller class should extend the `ControllerBase` class. Remember to add the appropriate `use` statements at the beginning of the file containing the controller class.